# converting dynamic content to JSON

Tags: json, azure, dynamic-content

I'm building a pipeline who sends a secret to the rest API of Azure key-vault with the Azure data factory tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/set-secret/set-secret). If I set the secret hardcoded then it works fine but if I replace it with my dynamic content variable it gives a newline error. Does anyone has a solution for this problem?
[click here for an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbRZa.png)

The working code:

```
{
"values": "test"
}
```

the not working code:

```
{
"values": @variables('push_refresh_token')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @*AnnuKumari-MSFT* & @*KoenVerschuren-6858* Posting your solutions as answer in community wiki to beneficial other community members for the similar issue.

Here is the workaround from [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/901332/converting-dynamic-content-to-json.html):-

> We need to add quotes to the variable with concatenate:-  For
> example:-
>
> To set variable:
>
> ```
> @concat('"', string(activity('get_auth_code').output.refresh_token),'"')
> ```
>
> which is followed by in web;
>
> ```
> @concat('{"value":', variables('push_refresh_token'),'}')
> ```